# Mockito match any class argument

Tags: java, class, mockito, arguments, matcher

Is there a way to match any class argument of the below sample routine?

```
class A {
     public B method(Class<? extends A> a) {}
}
```

How can I **always** return a `new B()` regardless of which class is passed into `method`? The following attempt only works for the specific case where `A` is matched.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
when(a.method(eq(A.class))).thenReturn(b);
```

---

**EDIT**: One solution is

```
(Class<?>) any(Class.class)
```

Comment: Your (Class<?>) any(Class.class) solution should be the answer here. I'd much rather use that then the ClassOrSubclassMatcher class seen below.

Comment: @superbAfterSemperPhi and johan-sjöberg I posted another way to do that, without cast. I believe that could be a better way. What do you think?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Two more ways to do it (see my comment on the previous answer by @Tomasz Nurkiewicz):

The first relies on the fact that the compiler simply won't let you pass in something of the wrong type:

```
when(a.method(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(b);
```

You lose the exact typing (the `Class<? extends A>`) but it probably works as you need it to.

The second is a lot more involved but is arguably a better solution if you *really* want to be sure that the argument to `method()` is an `A` or a subclass of `A`:

```
when(a.method(Matchers.argThat(new ClassOrSubclassMatcher<A>(A.class)))).thenReturn(b);
```

Where `ClassOrSubclassMatcher` is an `org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher` defined as:

```
public class ClassOrSubclassMatcher<T> extends BaseMatcher<Class<T>> {

    private final Class<T> targetClass;

    public ClassOrSubclassMatcher(Class<T> targetClass) {
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean matches(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            if (obj instanceof Class) {
                return targetClass.isAssignableFrom((Class<T>) obj);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void describeTo(Description desc) {
        desc.appendText("Matches a class or subclass");
    }       
}
```

Phew! I'd go with the first option until you *really* need to get finer control over what `method()` actually returns :-)

Comment: the `if (obj instanceof Class)` messes things up for me, so I removed it.

Comment: On the declaration line of the class, I had to change `extends BaseMatcher<Class<T>>` to just `extends BaseMatcher<T>`. Just FYI, if anyone else gets compile errors, try that out.

Comment: I also had to change the `matches` function to the following: ```public boolean matches(Object obj) {
  if (obj != null) {
   return targetClass.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass());
  }
  return false;
 }```

Comment: any(Class.class) is returning null - how can i avoid to return null

Comment: would be great if actually add the class that I need to import since now are many "any" from mockito

Answer (score 79):

There is another way to do that without cast:

```
when(a.method(Matchers.<Class<A>>any())).thenReturn(b);
```

This solution forces the method `any()` to return `Class<A>` type and not its default value (`Object`).

Comment: `Matchers` is deprecated in newer versions of Mockito and will likely be removed in version 3.0. Use `ArgumentMatchers` instead: `when(a.method(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<A>>any())).thenReturn(b);`

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

Comment: Perfect, the Matchers.<Class<Chain>>any() is the special sauce here! It lets you match a class of this type.

Answer (score 65):

**If you have no idea which Package you need to import:**

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
any(SomeClass.class)
```

OR

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
ArgumentMatchers.any(SomeClass.class)
```

Comment: This saved my life, I was accidentally importing "any" from hamcrest library.

Comment: Now it has changed to `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any`

Comment: There was 3 other possible packages, all reasonable that I could have picked. I wish more people provided the package name. Thank you.

Answer (score 30):

How about:

```
when(a.method(isA(A.class))).thenReturn(b);
```

or:

```
when(a.method((A)notNull())).thenReturn(b);
```

Comment: These would compile and work if the method signature was `method(A a)` - but it's (effectively) `method(Class<A> a)` - so you'd need to use: `when(a.method(isA(Class.class))).thenReturn(b);` or `when(a.method((Class<A>) notNull())).thenReturn(b);`

Comment: second part for me works as charm. 
fight with any(SomeClass.class) lead to a dead end. But (SomeClass.class) notNull() saved my day

Comment: If you have two methods with the same name but different arguments you can disambiguate the method to be mocked using the second version here. The first version did not cut it for me (on Java 8 that is).

Comment: Thanks, isA(A.class) works for me just fine and the mvcConversionService select the right class. This was not working with any(A.class) and eq(A.class).

Answer (score 12):

the solution from millhouse is not working anymore with recent version of mockito

This solution work with java 8 and mockito 2.2.9

where `ArgumentMatcher` is an instanceof `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher`

```
public class ClassOrSubclassMatcher<T> implements ArgumentMatcher<Class<T>> {

   private final Class<T> targetClass;

    public ClassOrSubclassMatcher(Class<T> targetClass) {
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Class<T> obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            if (obj instanceof Class) {
                return targetClass.isAssignableFrom( obj);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the use

```
when(a.method(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(new ClassOrSubclassMatcher<>(A.class)))).thenReturn(b);
```

Comment: the instanceof condition is not necessary anymore, and I wrote a convenience method: `public static <T> Class<T> subClassOf(Class<T> targetClass) {
    return argThat(new ClassOrSubclassMatcher<>(targetClass));
  }`

Answer (score 1):

**None of the examples above worked for me, as I'm required to mock one method multiple times for different class type parameters.**

Instead, this works.

```
//Handle InstrumentType.class
Mockito.doReturn(new InstrumentTypeMapper() {
    @Override
    public InstrumentType map(String sourceType) throws Exception {
        return InstrumentType.Unknown;
    }
}).when(mappingLoader).load(any(ServiceCode.class), argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Class<InstrumentType>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Class<InstrumentType> argument) {
        return InstrumentType.class.isAssignableFrom(argument);
    }
}));

//Handle InstrumentSubType.class    
Mockito.doReturn(new InstrumentSubTypeMapper() {
    @Override
    public InstrumentSubType map(String sourceType) throws Exception {
        return InstrumentSubType.istNone;
    }
}).when(mappingLoader).load(any(ServiceCode.class), argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Class<InstrumentSubType>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Class<InstrumentSubType> argument) {
        return InstrumentSubType.class.isAssignableFrom(argument);
    }
}));
```

**This is the short version:**

```
Mockito.doReturn(new InstrumentTypeMapper() {
    @Override
    public InstrumentType map(String sourceType) throws Exception {
        return InstrumentType.Unknown;
    }
}).when(mappingLoader).load(any(ServiceCode.class), argThat((ArgumentMatcher<Class<InstrumentType>>) InstrumentType.class::isAssignableFrom));

Mockito.doReturn(new InstrumentSubTypeMapper() {
    @Override
    public InstrumentSubType map(String sourceType) throws Exception {
        return InstrumentSubType.istNone;
    }
}).when(mappingLoader).load(any(ServiceCode.class), argThat((ArgumentMatcher<Class<InstrumentSubType>>) InstrumentSubType.class::isAssignableFrom));
```

As you can see, I'm using custom **ArgumentMatchers** together with **argThat**, not sure if there is a shorter way that also works.