# Using mockito.verify to ignore one of the parameters

Tags: mockito, verify

I want to skip checking one of the parameters in a verify call.  So for:

```
def allowMockitoVerify=Mockito.verify(msg,atLeastOnce()).handle(1st param,,3rd param)
```

I want to skip checking for the second parameter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately Mockito wont allow you to mix and match raw values and matchers (e.g. String and Matchers.any())

However you can use the eq() Matcher to match against a specific value, for example

```
Mockito.verify(msg, atLeastOnce())
  .handle(eq("someValue"), any(Thing.class), eq("anotherValue"));
```

Thanks to this post for a good example of this
[Mockito: InvalidUseOfMatchersException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845690/mockito-invaliduseofmatchersexception)

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Mockito.any()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500312/mockito-match-any-class-argument), which basically means we are not interested in this parameter.

Comment: Look to @david's answer

Comment: Okay so this answer should be deleted if it cannot stand on its own.

Comment: I first edit it but wrote same as in David's answer. I decided to give credits to him and deleted change and mentioned him. Fill free to vote to close answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Mockito `3.9.0` and because you cannot mix matchers with expected values, i.e, you can't verify that the first argument is a specific string like `test-profile` and the second is anything, so you need to convert all to matchers, so you **can't** do something like:

```
verify(userAuthorizationService).authorizeRequest("test-profile", any());
```

Instead, you need to convert values into matchers, like:

```
    verify(userAuthorizationService).authorizeRequest(matches("test-profile"), any());
```

Note the `matches` and `any` are static imports from `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`